# Difference in memory leaks using _crtBreakAlloc compared to UMDH

Tags: memory-leaks, visual-studio-2019, windbg, umdh

While trying to diagnose memory leaks with the `{,,ucrtbased.dll}_crtBreakAlloc` method, I found a memory leak which depends on timing in a multithreaded environment. Due to the multithreading, it's no longer predictable, which allocation number the leak in question will get. Using `_crtBreakAlloc` in Visual Studio, I get a total of less than 20 memory leaks reported.

Because I can't conclude over different runs in Visual Studio with these multithreading issues, I decided to take a different approach using UMDH. I enabled the GFlags User Mode Stack Trace Database (UST) and took a snapshot at the initial breakpoint in WinDbg and another snapshot just before process exit.

UMDH reports more than 1000 memory leaks, a lot of them which have .NET as part of the call stack (`clr!something+X`), but also others (I call them "native").

I want to figure out which filter I could use in [UmdhGui](https://github.com/ATrefzer/UmdhGui) in order to reduce the results to the same amount.

What kind of decision making does Visual Studio or `_crtBreakAlloc` apply so that it reports less than 20 leaks?

Comment: No solution, but thanks for sharing UmdhGui! I had no idea that it existed.

Answer (score 0):

`_crtBreakAlloc` and the entire `_crtXXX` family take care of allocations made through C-runtime. On the other hand, umdh collects allocations made through Win32 `HeapAlloc`. Modern C-runtimes end up calling `HeapAlloc` hence, you'll see in umdh dump both: all C-runtime allocations and allocations made by direct calls to `HeapAlloc`.

As to your practical question, here is what I can suggest:

1. You can filter out allocations from C-runtime by module name: `ucrtbase.dll` (or `ucrtbased.dll` for debug builds)
2. It will be much simpler if you manage to narrow the scope of umdh diff. Usually, you know which activity in your application causes a leak. Then you take the first dump right before initiating the activity and take the second dump when the activity is over.